# Как правильно указать путь в виджете к js файлу (Yii2)?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Как правильно указать путь в виджете  к **js** файлу (Framework - Yii2)?

---

Допустим, **test.js** файл лежит в

```
basic/components/widgets/assets/js
```

---

само **view** виджета, находится в

```
basic/components/widgets/view/mywidget.php
```

---

вот сам код view, нашего виджета. Как **правильно** указать путь, и почему именно так?

```
     <?php
     use yii\helpers\Html;
     ?>


      <?= Html::script('', ['type' => 'text/javascript', 'src' => 'вот тут должен быть наш путь к js']); ?>
        <?php
          echo "Путь к js скрипту - ";
        ?>
```

Стоит ли использовать псевдонимы типа **@web** ... или лучше **__DIR__** или **@app** или **AssetBundle**  или еще что то, например **AssetBundle**?

Comment: а почему не через $this->registerJsFile('path/to/myfile');и через алиас не подключить ?

Comment: @Sergalas Можно. А что значит - path/to/?  Просто я не знаю как лучше.

Comment: Тут надо указать путь ну через алиасы к примеру или urlManager

Comment: @Sergalas через AssetBundle советуют на проф форуме по Yii2. А вообще конечно можно и как вы пишите. Опубликуйте ответ и я вам поставлю "спасибку".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно оформить через

```
$this->registerJsFile('path/to/myfile')
```

где 'path/to/myfile' это путь к файлу который можно оформит через urlManager, алиасы ну или как советуют на форуме через AssetBundle путей много а какой из них выбирать вам :)